# why is my binary search is slower then linear search (python)

Tags: python, binary

I have a data frame containing 1,000,000 rows of list of lists of separated words like this:

```
kk=[['united','states'],
    ['love','hate'],
    ['united','states'],
    ['apple','inc'],
    ['united','states']].
```

And a country list:

```
k=['afghanistan','albania','algeria',.......]
```

I'm trying to apply function del_countries to a this df that has 1,000,000 more rows:

```
df.apply(lambda x:del_countries(x))
```

Why is the binary search a little bit slower than linear search? How should I solve it?

I have tried applying it to a single list of lists:

```
kk=[['united','states'],
    ['love','hate'],
    ['united','states'],
    ['apple','inc'],
    ['united','states']].
```

And binary search took only half the time that the linear search needed.

```
def binary_strSearch(nations,country):

    cdef int first=0
    cdef int last=len(nations)-1
    found=False
    while (first<=last) and found==False:
        middle=(first+last)//2
        if nations[middle]==country:
            found=True
        else:
            if country<nations[middle]:
                last=middle-1
            else:
                first=middle+1
    return found

 nations=['afghanistan','albania','algeria','america','andorra','angola','antigua','argentina','armenia','australia','austria','azerbaijan','bahamas','bahrain','bangladesh','barbados','belarus','belgium','belize','benin','bhutan','bissau','bolivia','bosnia','botswana','brazil','british','brunei','bulgaria','burkina','burma','burundi','cambodia','cameroon','canada','cape verde','central african republic','chad','chile','china','colombia','comoros','congo','costa rica','country debt','croatia','cuba','cyprus','czech','denmark','djibouti','dominica','east timor','ecuador','egypt','el salvador','emirate','england','eritrea','estonia','ethiopia','fiji','finland','france','gabon','gambia','georgia','germany','ghana','great britain','greece','grenada','grenadines','guatemala','guinea','guyana','haiti','herzegovina','honduras','hungary','iceland','in usa','india','indonesia','iran','iraq','ireland','israel','italy','ivory coast','jamaica','japan','jordan','kazakhstan','kenya','kiribati','korea','kosovo','kuwait','kyrgyzstan','laos','latvia','lebanon','lesotho','liberia','libya','liechtenstein','lithuania','luxembourg','macedonia','madagascar','malawi','malaysia','maldives','mali','malta','marshall','mauritania','mauritius','mexico','micronesia','moldova','monaco','mongolia','montenegro','morocco','mozambique','myanmar','namibia','nauru','nepal','netherlands','new zealand','nicaragua','niger','nigeria','norway','oman','pakistan','palau','panama','papua','paraguay','peru','philippines','poland','portugal','qatar','romania','russia','rwanda','saint kitts','samoa','san marino','santa lucia','sao tome','saudi arabia','scotland','scottish','senegal','serbia','seychelles','sierra leone','singapore','slovakia','slovenia','solomon','somalia','south africa','south sudan','spain','sri lanka','st kitts','st lucia','st. kitts','st. lucia','sudan','suriname','swaziland','sweden','switzerland','syria','taiwan','tajikistan','tanzania','thailand','tobago','togo','tonga','trinidad','tunisia','turkey','turkmenistan','tuvalu','uganda','ukraine','united kingdom','united states','uruguay','usa','uzbekistan','vanuatu','vatican','venezuela','vietnam','wales','welsh','yemen','zambia','zimbabwe']

def del_countries(x):
    print('cleaning countries')
    #[x.pop(i) for i,k in enumerate(x) if ' '.join(k) in nations] the linear search
    [x.pop(i) for i,k in enumerate(x) if binary_strSearch(nations,' 
'.join(k))]
    return x
```

Comment: There is no binary search and no linear search in your posted code.  `del_countries` is undefined; there is no output, no evidence of the timing problem.

Comment: Are you leaving out the time needed to build the tree?   You need to do that and ONLY time the search part after building your tree.  Search is only faster for an existing tree not always if you also add in the time to build it.

Comment: `lambda x: del_countries(x)` is just `del_countries`, but with an extra runtime layer.

Comment: @Prune Is it better now?

Comment: @chepner I will try removing that layer, thank you.

Comment: 3 suggestions: use `bisect` module; compare timing with larger `nations` list; use `frozenset(nations)` instead.

Comment: You still haven't handled all of the points I made earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Are your lists sorted before the binary search is applied?  Binary search is only effective if it knows the string you're looking for will have smaller or bigger character values than what it finds in the middle on each subsequent binary split of the array.